# Amount not getting correctly in stripe

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, stripe-payments

I am using stripe payment gateway in my website and I have created subscription plan at stripe website and that all planes I will listed at my website.

My website is build with asp.net C#. I have used https://github.com/jaymedavis/stripe.net library project's dll and I'm getting incorrect pricing while listing of plans.

**Example: I have entered 15.50 for a particular product an din response of listing from strip I am getting converted amount as 1550.**

Suggest if anyone use before it or have any solution for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid rounding errors, all amounts in Stripe's API are in cents (or more accurately, they are in the [smallest unit for that currency](https://support.stripe.com/questions/which-zero-decimal-currencies-does-stripe-support)).

So if you want to create a charge for $15.50, you need to pass `amount=1550` and `currency="usd"` in your [charge creation request](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_charge).